# List Slicing in a Conditional Statement

Tags: python, list

This is the code I'm referring to the above question,

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

if(another_list == my_list[2:]):
   print("good")
else:
   print("bad")
```

In the code sample above, is *my_list[2:] stored in the memory* (like we assigned it to a variable)? Or is it forgotten after the conditional is over?

Comment: Are you asking if the list is cached in between calls? Or if the list is deleted after the condition has been checked?

Comment: I mean the second statement you mentioned.

Comment: Yes, it is stored in the memory. It is most likely deleted at some time after the condition is checked and the data is not needed any more. I *think* the memory management may differ among python implementations (cpython, jython). What are your specific concerns?

Comment: I was curious whether it is deleted after the conditions are checked. I am a beginner, so I don't what you mean by "python implementations" @Jan Stránský

Comment: If your code is inside a function and you don't return the list, then yes your list will be deleted. Generally speaking, objects will be removed from memory (garbage collected) when they are no longer referenced by anyone. For further information you should read up on scopes and maybe garbage collection in python.

Comment: @Josef is deletion of `my_list[2:]` (not assigned to any variable) somehow influenced by being inside function or not?

Comment: @FrenkFrenk ad "python implementations", it depends on definition of "python". If the language, syntax, etc. or specific "executable". The "standard" is CPython, but there are [other variants](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonImplementations). Each of them could manage memory differently.

Comment: @JanStránský He propably doesn't mean implementation details. If the condition is called again, after `my_list` got changed the condition will be evaluated again with the new values, no caching.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't assign it to a variable so it isn't stored. It is forgotten after the conditional but it will always work when the program is run again if the program is more or less the same.

Comment: Depends on definition of "stored". At least for the time of comparison it definitely is stored in the memory

Comment: By storing, I meant even storing when it is no longer used (the situation after the conditional statement). @JanStránský